# apply macro to Flask FormField

Tags: javascript, html, flask, macros, flask-wtforms

I have forms in flask like so:

```
class form1(Form):
    count1=IntegerRangeField('count1')
    count2=IntegerRangeField('count2')

class form2(Form):
    Incoming=FormField(form1)
    Outgoing=FormField(form1)
```

In the template, I render the fields, with a loop which runs a macro depending on the field type:

```
{% macro render(form) %}
<script type='text/javascript'>
function updateRangeInput(elem) {
  $(elem).next().val($(elem).val());
}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
{% if field.type in ["IntegerRangeField","FormField"] %}
{{field.name}}
{{field(min=0, max=25, oninput="updateRangeInput(this)")}}
<output><script> document.write() </script > </output>
{% else %}
</body>
{% endmacro %}
```

The macro does not display the slider integer chosen for IntegerRangeFields (macro) but the fields do render on the page. How can I get IntegerRangeFields underlying FormFields to apply the macro?

note: if I used IntegerRangeFields directly in place form FormField, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a matter of actually accessing the underlying fields within the 'subform' rather than the FormField itself.

We can apply the macro to `count1` and `count2` via:

```
{% for field in form.Incoming.form %}
{{field(min=0, max=25, oninput="updateRangeInput(this)")}}
<output><script> document.write() </script > </output>
{% endfor %}
```